# How do I listen for changes for all documents in a subcollection in firestore?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I want to listen to changes in the `chats` collection for all docs in the `messages` collection but can't find a method that'll allow that.

```
  updateUsersListOnChange = loadUsersCallback => {
    return firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("messages")
      .doc(/* all docs */)
      .collection("chats")
      .onSnapshot(() => {
        loadUsersCallback();
      });
  };
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're describing is known as a collection group query, a query across a group of collections.

```
db.collectionGroup("chats").onSnapshot(() => {
    loadUsersCallback();
});
```

This will load the documents from all collections named `chats` across your entire database. There is no way to indicate a path, so you'll want to ensure that your collection names are unique enough to allow you to identify the right by by their name alone.

For more on this, see the documentation on [collection group queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query).